# responsive category icons should cover all available DIV area using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

While re-sizing the browser I want there should not be any blank space on right side in DIV where class .categoryTableArea is applied, instead the category icon should be re-sized. If the size of the category icons reaches the minumum icon size it should wrap/move to next line.

Responsive category icons should cover all available area in DIV where class .categoryTableArea is applied.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FC0;
}

.categoryTableArea {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.categoryArea {
    min-width: 110px;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}


.categoryIcon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 88px;
    background-color: blue; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 4px;
}


.categoryName {
    color: #666666;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #2f2f2f; 
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="categoryTableArea">
  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 01</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 02</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 03</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 04</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 05</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 06</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 07</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 08</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 09</p>
  </div>


  <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
    <p class=categoryName>Category Name 10</p>
  </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using flexbox

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FC0;
}
.categoryTableArea {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.categoryArea {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 110px;
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}
.categoryIcon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 88px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.categoryName {
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="categoryTableArea">
    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 01</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 02</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 03</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 04</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 05</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 06</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 07</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 08</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 09</p>
    </div>


    <div class="categoryArea">
      <div class="categoryIcon">
        Image
      </div>
      <p class=categoryName>Category Name 10</p>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For further information check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: "+1" for teaching new property and using it effectively, `flex` is indeed a very useful property and we should use it effectively due to its greater uses.